# Laravel: belongsToMany with additional fields

Tags: laravel

Object `Page` has any number of `Widgets` and every `Page-Widget` pair has special options (for example, position, custom title).

I just made

```
class Page extends Model {
    public function widgets(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Widget');
    }
}
...
class Widget extends Model {
}
```

I added more columns to `page_widget` table (position, settings...).

How could I access/update them via `$page->widget->position`? I also need ability to get page widgets sorted by that `position`.

Please suggest Model relations. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you have a many-to-many relationship, you have a pivot-table called `pages_widget`. You can add the columns to that table and access the values with `pivot`. Take a look the final part of Many to Many relations (namely Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns), on [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Just to add to @milz comment. A _pivot table_ is just a _join table_ that has extra columns (e.g. your `position`).

Answer (score 4):

You can add extra fields like this:

```
class Page extends Model {
    public function widgets(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Widget')->withPivot('position', 'settings);
    }
}
```

Then, to create that row in db, you do:

```
$page->widgets()->attach($widgetId, ['position' => $position, 'settings' => $settings]);
```

To access data in pivot table you can do:

```
foreach ($page->widgets as $widget) {
    echo $widget->pivot->position;
    echo $widget->pivot->settings;
}
```

There's a lot of information in the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many